# Typescript: how to return subclass type from inherited static property?

Tags: typescript, static, subclass

```
class BaseDoc {
    static Collection;  
    static find(){
        // which is expected to return an instance of SubDoc when run SubDoc.find()
        return this.Collection.find();  
    }
}

class SubDoc extends BaseDoc {}
```

What I hope is: When running SubDoc.find(), the app knows the type of the return value to be an instance of SubDoc rather than BaseDoc.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can create a generic version of `find` that will have the `this` parameter inferred to the type of the class it's being called on, and use `InstanceType<T>` to extract the actual instance type from the class type:

```
class BaseDoc {
    static Collection: any;
    static find<T extends typeof BaseDoc>(this: T): InstanceType<T> {
        // which is expected to return an instance of SubDoc when run SubDoc.find()
        return this.Collection.find();
    }
}

class SubDoc extends BaseDoc {

}

SubDoc.find() // return SubDoc
```

Or you can mandate that the derived class defines a generic `Collection` member of the appropriate type:

```
class Collection<T> {
    find(): T {
        return null as any // dummy imeplmentation
    }
}
type GetCollectionItem<T extends Collection<any>> = T extends Collection<infer U> ? U: never;

class BaseDoc {
    static Collection: Collection<BaseDoc>;
    static find<T extends { new (... args: any[]) : any, Collection: Collection<any> }>(this: T):  GetCollectionItem<T['Collection']> {
        // which is expected to return an instance of SubDoc when run SubDoc.find()
        return this.Collection.find();
    }
}

class SubDoc extends BaseDoc {
    static Collection: Collection<SubDoc>;
}

SubDoc.find() // return SubDoc
```

Comment: Awesome! It rocks!

Comment: when SubDoc has a constructor(public prop), it will report error: [ts] The 'this' context of type 'typeof SubDoc' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'typeof DocBase'.

Comment: @DC Sorry I took a while to get back, I was putting the child to bed :). You can use the approach in my second example, just `typeof BasDoc` will unfortunately mandate an empty constructor. This should work `static find<T extends { new (... args: any[]) : BaseDoc, Collection: any }>(this: T): InstanceType<T>`

Comment: Thank you very much! It works again! BTW, I prefer your 1st example for its simplicity.

Comment: @DC yeah, it is simpler, unfortunately simple does not always work :(

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Can someone explain how the first example works?

Comment: @Dylan `this` will be the class itself for the static method. If we use a generic type parameter such as `T` for the `this` parameter, ts will infer into `T` the actual class that the static method is called on, so `T` will be `typeof SubDoc` and then we extarct the instance type using `InstanceType`. Let me know if it's more clear now, or if not, let me know what is tripping you up. 

Comment: Just can't wrap my head around why going `find<T extends BaseDoc>(this: T): T` doesn't work. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @Dylan `BaseDoc` is the instance type, `typeof BaseDoc` is the class type. Whane you call an instance method this is an instance of the type so `this` will be of the same type as the instance type. When you call a static method, `this` will be the class itself (since that is what the method gets called on) so `this` will be something that extends `typeof BaseDoc`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Makes sense now, thankyou for your help.